# 2 Routers, 2 Default Gateways, but i need one static IP for each System

Tags: networking, ip

we have 2 routers in our office, BSNL & AIrtel, BSNL default gateway is-192.168.2.1 & Airtel  default gateway is-192.168.1.1, so can anybody tell how do i configure static IP addresses to all windows systems & printer so that whenever i change BSNL or Airtel LAN connection. same IP address should stay with computer & printer as well.

Comment: Im very unsure of the Router Configuration or the UI could you add a photo of the UI. You could also set the static IP on each computer under the adapter settings. Just change it from DHCP and enter in your Default gateway and give each computer in the office its own ip so the first one you do would need to be 192.168.2.2 for the 192.168.2.1 gateway and so on. Same for the Default gateway of 192.168.1.1 you would go to 192.168.1.2 and so on.

Comment: Why not just number them both inside the same network, say 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2? Then you can choose a router by changing the default gateway.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You should expand this into an answer (as I was just going to do).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are turning off 1 device and turning on the other, this is a hard problem to solve without additional hardware.

If you can *absolutely* ensure only 1 device will be on at a time, you can statically set the IP's and gateway on all your devices (for example to 192.168.1.x), and then reconfigure your second router (in this case the BSNL one) to 192.168.1.1 to match the gateway of the Airtel connection)

That said, the correct solution is to get a 3 port router - 1 for each WAN interface and 1 for the LAN interface.  You can then load balance / change configurations on the WAN ports without making changes on the LAN ports, and without fear of DHCP issues.  You can get "load balancing routers" which do what you want, or you can get a DD-WRT compatible router and role your own if you have the skill and time.

Unfortunately having 2 routers on at the same time on the same subnet doing what you are asking is extremely tricky - you you will have issues with changing default gateways for a start.